# ¿Obtener fila específica de un row number SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Por curiosidad y conocimiento, me gustaría saber como obtener valores específicos de un `row_number()`, a continuación les diré un ejemplo. Si tengo una query como esta, donde quiero obtener todo los datos de una re calificación de datos, osea cuando se modificó la fecha de registro:

```
select 
     id, 
     fecha_ingreso,
     row_number() over(partition by id order by fecha_ingreso asc) rep
from tabla
```

En donde obtengo datos como estos:

```
+------+----------+----+
|id    |fecha     |rep |
+------+----------+----+
|1     |2019-01-01|1   |
+------+----------+----+
|2     |2019-01-05|1   |
+------+----------+----+
|2     |2019-01-07|2   |
+------+----------+----+
|3     |2019-01-08|1   |
+------+----------+----+
|3     |2019-01-09|2   |
+------+----------+----+
|3     |2019-01-12|3   |
+------+----------+----+
```

Y quisiera traer solo el segundo valor del `row_number()` `(rep)`, pero que incluya los registros que tienen un solo valor, osea, que me devuelva algo como esto:

```
+------+----------+----+
|id    |fecha     |rep |
+------+----------+----+
|1     |2019-01-01|1   |
+------+----------+----+
|2     |2019-01-07|2   |
+------+----------+----+
|3     |2019-01-09|2   |
+------+----------+----+
```

Alguna sugerencia o si es posible de otra manera?.

Comment: no entiendo tu pregunta se mas claro con un solo valor te refieres a?? porque en tu ejemplo rep devuelve 1,2 y 3 y en el resultado esperando 1y 2

Comment: He leído varias veces tu pregunta y no comprendo que es lo que quieres lograr...

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas dos cosas:

- Enumeración según id por fecha ascendente
- Cantidad de repeticiones del id, para identificar cuando solo exista uno.

Lo podrías realizar de la siguiente manera, utilizando una consulta anidada.

```
declare @tabla table (id int,fecha_ingreso date)
insert into @tabla values (1,'2019-01-01')
insert into @tabla values (2,'2019-01-05')
insert into @tabla values (2,'2019-01-07')
insert into @tabla values (3,'2019-01-08')
insert into @tabla values (3,'2019-01-09')
insert into @tabla values (3,'2019-01-12')

SELECT id, fecha_ingreso, rep
FROM (  SELECT 
                id, 
                fecha_ingreso,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY fecha_ingreso ASC) rep,
                COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY id) cnt
        FROM @tabla) tbl
WHERE tbl.rep = 2 OR tbl.cnt = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas tener una forma de definir cuales tienen una fila y cuales tienen más de una. Aquí hay un ejemplo.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    select 
         id, 
         fecha_ingreso,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY fecha_ingreso asc) AS rep,
         COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY fecha_ingreso asc) AS cuantos
    from tabla
)
SELECT id,
    fecha_ingreso,
    rep
FROM CTE
WHERE rep = 2
OR cuantos = 1;
```